# How to save html document as pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, pdf-generation

I want to open a web page and save it as pdf. I have to use chrome's "Save as Pdf" feature. I dont want to use any paid library. Is it possible to open html page in chrome browser and save it as pdf programatically in c#.

Comment: I know about many of the libraries like iTextSharp. but I want to know  how is it possible to do it using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not save html page as a PDF without any third party DLL like iTextsharp and many others which are available in Free.
So, you can use this Free DLL for save as PDF.